# React - Fill array in state with input value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have an empty link array and three input fields on my page.
I want to get the values of all three input fields in one array in my state variable link[] so that I can send a link array to my DB.
Like you see I am using semantic ui but for the input fields there is just the onChange function I can use

How can I do that?

```js
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {          
            link : []          
        };
```

```html
render() {
        
        
        return (
            <Grid style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <Grid.Column width={6} className='dashboardCard'>
                    <Card fluid>
                        <Card.Content >
                            <Card.Header>Allgemeine Künstler-Daten</Card.Header>
                            <Card.Description>
                                "Strange Fruit" is a song performed most famously by Billie
                                Holiday, who first sang and recorded it in 1939.
                            </Card.Description>
                        </Card.Content>
                        <Card.Content extra textAlign="center">
                            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                                <Input
                                    fluid
                                    label="Social Link 1"
                                    placeholder="www.twitter.com/artist"
                                    style={{ margin: "1rem" }}
                                    width={6}
                                    name="link"
                                    value={this.state.link}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                />
                                <Input
                                    fluid
                                    label="Social Link 2"
                                    placeholder="www.soundcloud.com/artist"
                                    style={{ margin: "1rem" }}
                                    width={6}
                                    name="link"
                                    value={this.state.link}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                />
                                <Input
                                    fluid
                                    label="Social Link 3"
                                  placeholder="www.facebook.com/artist"
                                    style={{ margin: "1rem" }}
                                    width={6}
                                    name="link"
                                    value={this.state.link}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                />
                                <Dropdown
                                <Form.Button positive     
                                      value="Submit">Save</Form.Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Content>
                    </Card>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column columns={5} />
            </Grid>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not storing the links in an array but as separate values with distinct keys in your component's state. That way you'll know which link to update if the user changes something. Just have keys in the state that correspond to inputs that are rendered, using the `<input>` `name` attribute. It's also convenient to wrap all of the data from the form in a `formOptions` key in the state in case you have other state data.

You can do something like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    formOptions: {
      link1: '',
      link2: '',
      link3: ''
    }
  };
}

handleInputChange = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  const { formOptions } = this.state;
  formOptions[name] = value;
  this.setState({ formOptions });
}
```

Then just give your inputs the name attributes `link1`, `link2`, and `link3`.

Then in your `handleSubmit` method, you can convert the separate links into a single array if that's how you need to send them.

Note that the method `handleInputChange` needs to be written as an attribute assigned to an arrow function for binding `this` to the component so that the state can be accessed. Alternatively you can just define `handleInputChange` normally and then in each input's `onChange` put `this.handleInputChange.bind(this)`, but I find the first way a bit cleaner.